# Setting default font-size in android app

Tags: android, android-fonts

I am developing an app in android,i just need to know how to set the font of my app so that it can adjust according to the various android devices. In my case when i am opening my app in samsung galaxy note device the font of my app appears very small. Guidance required so that my app will auto adjust the font in any android device or tablet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dp instead of px for textsize.
See this question: 
[What is the difference between "px", "dp", "dip" and "sp" on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-of-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use different layout files for different screen as well as different density. Give your fonts size in those layout file. Android will load layout according to screens.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: i would recommend having only one layout file if your fundamental layout isnt changing and moving information like his into styles. this way you can easily make changes to layout by only changing one file